# number of files; date creation and file size

Tags: python, bash, shell

desperately need your help - i have a folder which consists of many files created different days and has different quantity and different size.
For a file size measure i use :

```
find . -name "*20160725*" -print -exec du -ks {} \; | cut -f1 | awk '{total=total+$1}END{print total/1024}'
```

for file quantity

```
ls -l | grep -c "Jul 25"
```

and my question how to SUM them to make some kinda script which will export file in a such view:

```
DATE    QUANTITY SIZE
05-jul  416 26,84
06-jul  1170    28,6
07-jul  490 27,53
08-jul  794 16,19
09-jul  112 13,47
10-jul  122 18,53
11-jul  698 34,04
12-jul  456 19,4
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
find . -name '*' -printf '%Td-%Tb %s\n' | awk  'NR==1 {print "DATE\tQUANTITY\tSIZE"}{a[$1]+=$2;b[$1]+=1;}END{for(i in a)print i"\t"b[i]"\t"a[i]/1024}'
```

The `printf` option of the `find` command outputs date and size for each file.

The ouput is piped to `awk` that  sum the sizes for each date and convert byte sizes to kilobytes as in your sample output.

**Update**

To sort by date using `mm/dd/yyyy` format:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*' -printf '%TD %s\n' | awk  'NR==1 {print "DATE\tQUANTITY\tSIZE"}{a[$1]+=$2;b[$1]+=1;}END{for(i in a)print i"\t"b[i]"\t"a[i]/1024}' | sort -n -t"/" -k3 -k1 -k2
```

Comment: Great; worked perfect!! You helped me a lot!!Not enough experience to put 5+

Comment: You're welcome :) You may accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: Thanks for your work; but it shows weird result like:  14-Jul 145 35408.8
but other command shows me different result : find . -maxdepth 1 -printf '%CY%Cm%Cd.%CH%CM\t%s\t%f\n'|grep -c '20160714'
files - 1385 :(
Maybe the reason of that because we have more than 10000 files in that folder?

Comment: 26-Jul 871 4274.85
[root@server01 folder]# ls -l|grep -c 'Jul 26'
710

Comment: yes!! maxdepth-1; you are my god 10000000000 times thanks